# .htaccess redirect to subfolder in different domain, maintaining old domain in the URL

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, redirects

Redirect has been widely discussed and most problems solved, so I am sorry for opening yet another post about this, but none of the codes I am trying work.

I have a WordPress site hosted in `http://mydomain.com/clientsdomain.com/wordpress`

I would like to temporarily redirect `http://clientsdomain.com/` to the abovementioned URL, maintaining the clientsdomain.com domain in the URL.

So for example `http://clientsdomain.com/some/page` would be pointing to `http://mydomain.com/clientsdomain.com/wordpress/some/page`

Is this even possible with .htaccess? Maybe som configuration or plugin option with WordPress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.htaccess` is unlikely to be sufficient (of course, in principle `.htaccess` is just a place for local configuration, it depends on which modules are available too).

**EDIT:** (more details on why [`mod_rewrite`/redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html#movehomedirs)) doesn't work)

Assuming that by `.htaccess` you're referring to the usual [`mod_rewrite`/redirect directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html#movehomedirs), this will not work because the browser will be redirected, so the actual (redirected) URL will be visible in the location bar (`http://mydomain.com/clientsdomain.com/wordpress`), not the one initially requested (`http://clientsdomain.com/`).

`Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` will of course perform an external redirection: this will not maintain the old domain in the URL as requested.

`mod_rewrite` and `RewriteRule` provide two options for external links (see table at the end of the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) (and the [documentation about the flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r)):

- `^localpath(.*) http://otherhost/otherpath$1`

  `http://otherhost/otherpath/pathinfo` via external redirection
- `^localpath(.*) http://otherhost/otherpath$1 [R]`

  `http://otherhost/otherpath/pathinfo` via external redirection (the `[R]` flag is redundant)
- `^localpath(.*) http://otherhost/otherpath$1 [P]`

  `http://otherhost/otherpath/pathinfo` via internal proxy

The external redirection option (no flag or `[R]`) will be equivalent to `Redirect` and cause the URL in the address bar to change.

The internal proxy option (`[P]`) will not cause the URL in the address bar to change, but, unless the server behind the internal proxy is aware it needs to change the base URLs in the links it serves, this will cause problems with the links embedded within the page (this is what `mod_proxy_html` can address).

---

There are at least two possible options to keep the requested URL in the location bar:

### iframe

Keeping the original URL is typically done with an `iframe`. You could write a quick script (e.g. in PHP) that takes a URL (or part of it) as a query parameter.

For example, `http://clientsdomain.com/redirect.php?location=some/page` would create a page simply containing an iframe for `http://mydomain.com/clientsdomain.com/wordpress/some/page`. To make all the pages redirect from `http://clientsdomain.com/`, you could use a rewrite in `.htaccess` to `redirect.php?$1`.

In this context, `http://clientsdomain.com/some/page` would be rewritten as `http://clientsdomain.com/redirect.php?location=some/page`, which would contain an iframe pointing to `http://mydomain.com/clientsdomain.com/wordpress/some/page`.

One of the downsides is that, whenever a user clicks on a link the location bar will not change. It might also confuse some JavaScript scripts relying on the fragment (`#`).

### mod_proxy_html

Another solution, possibly harder to install especially if you're on a shared host, would be to use [`mod_proxy_html`](http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/) to reverse proxy `http://clientsdomain.com/` to `http://mydomain.com/clientsdomain.com/wordpress`.

This might be doable with `.htaccess` only (provided the module is installed), but I'm not sure: it depends whether its configuration directives are allowed in `.htaccess` or need to be in the global configuration. Either way, you'll almost certainly need full access to the Apache Httpd installation to configure this, so whether it's in `.htaccess` or in one of the main config files shouldn't really matter at this stage.

(A plain reverse proxy with `mod_proxy_http` without `mod_proxy_html` would allow you to proxy the requests, but wouldn't replace the links within the pages.)

Adding to this, you'll probably need `mod_header` on top of this (with any of the `mod_proxy_*`). The `Location` headers are absolute URLs according to the HTTP specification, so any redirect sent by the proxied server to itself (even simply for adding a trailing slash, for example) will have absolute URLs to itself. You can fix this problem using something along these lines (check whether the regexp and paths are correct when deploying):

```
Header edit Location ^http://mydomain.com/clientsdomain.com/wordpress http://clientsdomain.com/
```

(This being said, if the target Wordpress server is not to be used with its initial address, there may be an option or plugin to set its base URL to the new one, which could make `mod_proxy` handling easier.)

Comment: My mistake, you're right: `If an absolute URL is specified, mod_rewrite checks to see whether the hostname matches the current host. If it does, the scheme and hostname are stripped out and the resulting path is treated as a URL-path. Otherwise, an external redirect is performed for the given URL.`

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible with .htaccess. Not much more to say than that.